# Scraping for bottom row of table

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I'm using python 3.4. I know how to utilize [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) to scrape a webpage, but I'm trying to come up with the most efficient way to accomplish this. The [Nexus factory image page](https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images) (Android) contains lists of all Nexus devices and is updated when a new build is available. The newest builds are always added to the bottom of the respective table. I have a list of the names of each device, both real name and codename, and I only pull these (the devices themselves are only updated once/year, if that, and only some of the devices still receive updates).

**What would be the most efficient way to pull the bottom entry out of each table?** I plan to save each string from the first `<td>` in the bottom rows as pickled objects so I can easily compare strings later to check if the current bottom row is new, but I'm not sure what the best way would be to scrape for the entry itself.

Each `<tr>` has an id of the format `devnamebuildnumber`. Since I have the name of each device and will have the latest string, I should be able to search by that using `soup.find("tr", id=dev + buildstring)`. That returns every sibling and child of the found row, however, so I'm not sure how to best utilize that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is something to get you started. The idea is to get the `h2` elements with `id` attribute - except the very first element these would be the device name elements. For every element found, let's get the next `table` element and parse the versions into a list. Implementation:

```
from pprint import pprint

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "lxml")

data = {}
for device in soup.find_all("h2", id=True)[1:]:
    device_name = device.get_text(strip=True)

    data[device_name] = [version.find("td").get_text(strip=True)
                         for version in device.find_next("table").find_all("tr", id=True)]

pprint(data)
```

Prints the dictionary with device names as keys and versions as values:

```
{'"angler" for Nexus 6P': ['6.0.0 (MDA89D)',
                           '6.0.0 (MDB08K)',
                           '6.0.0 (MDB08L)',
                           '6.0.0 (MDB08M)',
                           '6.0.0 (MMB29N)',
                           '6.0.1 (MMB29M)',
                           '6.0.1 (MMB29P)'],
 '"bullhead" for Nexus 5X': ['6.0.0 (MDA89E)',
                             '6.0.0 (MDB08I)',
                             '6.0.0 (MDB08L)',
                             '6.0.0 (MDB08M)',
                             '6.0.1 (MMB29K)',
                             '6.0.1 (MMB29P)'],
 '"fugu" for Nexus Player': ['5.0 (LRX21M)',
                             '5.0 (LRX21V)',
                             '5.1.0 (LMY47D)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY47V)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY48J)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY48N)',
                             '6.0.0 (MRA58K)',
                             '6.0.0 (MRA58N)',
                             '6.0.1 (MMB29M)',
                             '6.0.1 (MMB29T)'],
 '"hammerhead" for Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE)': ['4.4 (KRT16M)',
                                        '4.4.2 (KOT49H)',
                                        '4.4.3 (KTU84M)',
                                        '4.4.4 (KTU84P)',
                                        '4.4.4 Release 2 (For 2Degrees/NZ, '
                                        'Telstra/AUS and India ONLY) (KTU84Q)',
                                        '5.0 (LRX21O)',
                                        '5.0.1 (LRX22C)',
                                        '5.1.0 (LMY47D)',
                                        '5.1.0 (LMY47I)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY48B)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY48I)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY48M)',
                                        '6.0.0 (MRA58K)',
                                        '6.0.0 (MRA58N)',
                                        '6.0.1 (MMB29K)',
                                        '6.0.1 (MMB29S)'],
 '"mantaray" for Nexus 10': ['4.2.2 (JDQ39)',
                             '4.3 (JWR66Y)',
                             '4.4 (KRT16S)',
                             '4.4.2 (KOT49H)',
                             '4.4.3 (KTU84L)',
                             '4.4.4 (KTU84P)',
                             '5.0 (LRX21P)',
                             '5.0.1 (LRX22C)',
                             '5.0.2 (LRX22G)',
                             '5.1.0 (LMY47D)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY47V)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY48I)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY48M)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY48T)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY48X)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY48Z)',
                             '5.1.1 (LMY49F)'],
 '"mysid" for Galaxy Nexus "toro" (Verizon CDMA/LTE)': ['4.0.4 (IMM76K)',
                                                        '4.1.1 (JRO03O)',
                                                        '4.2.2 (JDQ39)'],
 '"mysidspr" for Galaxy Nexus "toroplus" (Sprint CDMA/LTE)': ['4.1.1 (FH05)',
                                                              '4.2.1 (GA02)'],
 '"nakasi" for Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi)': ['4.1.2 (JZO54K)',
                                  '4.2.2 (JDQ39)',
                                  '4.3 (JWR66Y)',
                                  '4.4 (KRT16S)',
                                  '4.4.2 (KOT49H)',
                                  '4.4.3 (KTU84L)',
                                  '4.4.4 (KTU84P)',
                                  '5.0 (LRX21P)',
                                  '5.0.2 (LRX22G)',
                                  '5.1.0 (LMY47D)',
                                  '5.1.1 (LMY47V)'],
 '"nakasig" for Nexus 7 (Mobile)': ['4.2.2 (JDQ39)',
                                    '4.3 (JWR66Y)',
                                    '4.4 (KRT16S)',
                                    '4.4.2 (KOT49H)',
                                    '4.4.3 (KTU84L)',
                                    '4.4.4 (KTU84P)',
                                    '5.0.2 (LRX22G)',
                                    '5.1.0 (LMY47D)',
                                    '5.1.1 (LMY47V)'],
 '"occam" for Nexus 4': ['4.2.2 (JDQ39)',
                         '4.3 (JWR66Y)',
                         '4.4 (KRT16S)',
                         '4.4.2 (KOT49H)',
                         '4.4.3 (KTU84L)',
                         '4.4.4 (KTU84P)',
                         '5.0 (LRX21T)',
                         '5.0.1 (LRX22C)',
                         '5.1.0 (LMY47O)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY47V)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48I)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48M)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48T)'],
 '"razor" for Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi)': ['4.3 (JSS15Q)',
                                        '4.3 (JSS15R)',
                                        '4.4 (KRT16S)',
                                        '4.4.2 (KOT49H)',
                                        '4.4.3 (KTU84L)',
                                        '4.4.4 (KTU84P)',
                                        '5.0 (LRX21P)',
                                        '5.0.1 (LRX22C)',
                                        '5.0.2 (LRX22G)',
                                        '5.1.0 (LMY47O)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY47V)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY48G)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY48I)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY48M)',
                                        '5.1.1 (LMY48T)',
                                        '6.0.0 (MRA58K)',
                                        '6.0.0 (MRA58U)',
                                        '6.0.0 (MRA58V)',
                                        '6.0.1 (MMB29K)',
                                        '6.0.1 (MMB29O)'],
 '"razorg" for Nexus 7 [2013] (Mobile)': ['4.3 (JLS36C)',
                                          '4.3.1 (JLS36I)',
                                          '4.4 (KRT16S)',
                                          '4.4.2 (KOT49H)',
                                          '4.4.2_r2 (Verizon) (KVT49L)',
                                          '4.4.3 (KTU84L)',
                                          '4.4.4 (KTU84P)',
                                          '5.0.2 (LRX22G)',
                                          '5.1.0 (LMY47O)',
                                          '5.1.1 (LMY47V)',
                                          '5.1.1 (LMY48P)',
                                          '5.1.1 (LMY48U)',
                                          '5.1.1 (LMY48X)',
                                          '5.1.1 (LMY48Z)',
                                          '6.0.0 (MRA58K)',
                                          '6.0.0 (MRA58N)',
                                          '6.0.0 (MRA58V)',
                                          '6.0.0 (MRA59B)',
                                          '6.0.1 (MMB29K)',
                                          '6.0.1 (MMB29O)'],
 '"ryu" for Pixel C': ['6.0.1 (MXB48J)', '6.0.1 (MXB48K)'],
 '"shamu" for Nexus 6': ['5.0 (LRX21O)',
                         '5.0.1 (LRX22C)',
                         '5.1.0 (LMY47D)',
                         '5.1.0 (LMY47E)',
                         '5.1.0 (LMY47I)',
                         '5.1.0 (For T-Mobile ONLY) (LMY47M)',
                         '5.1.1 (All carriers except T-Mobile US) (LMY47Z)',
                         '5.1.1 (For T-Mobile ONLY) (LYZ28E)',
                         '5.1.1 (For Project Fi ONLY) (LVY48C)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48I)',
                         '5.1.1 (For T-Mobile ONLY) (LYZ28J)',
                         '5.1.1 (For Project Fi ONLY) (LVY48E)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48M)',
                         '5.1.1 (For T-Mobile ONLY) (LYZ28K)',
                         '5.1.1 (For Project Fi ONLY) (LVY48F)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48T)',
                         '5.1.1 (For T-Mobile ONLY) (LYZ28M)',
                         '5.1.1 (For Project Fi ONLY) (LVY48H)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48W)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48X)',
                         '5.1.1 (LMY48Y)',
                         '5.1.1 (For T-Mobile ONLY) (LYZ28N)',
                         '5.1.1 (For Project Fi ONLY) (LVY48I)',
                         '6.0.0 (MRA58K)',
                         '6.0.0 (MRA58N)',
                         '6.0.0 (MRA58R)',
                         '6.0.0 (MRA58X)',
                         '6.0.1 (MMB29K)',
                         '6.0.1 (MMB29S)'],
 '"soju" for Nexus S (worldwide version, i9020t and i9023)': ['2.3.6 (GRK39F)',
                                                              '4.0.4 (IMM76D)',
                                                              '4.1.2 (JZO54K)'],
 '"sojua" for Nexus S (850MHz version, i9020a)': ['2.3.6 (GRK39F)',
                                                  '4.0.4 (IMM76D)',
                                                  '4.1.2 (JZO54K)'],
 '"sojuk" for Nexus S (Korea version, m200)': ['2.3.6 (GRK39F)',
                                               '4.0.4 (IMM76D)',
                                               '4.1.1 (JRO03E)'],
 '"sojus" for Nexus S 4G (d720)': ['2.3.7 (GWK74)',
                                   '4.0.4 (IMM76D)',
                                   '4.1.1 (JRO03R)'],
 '"takju" for Galaxy Nexus "maguro" (GSM/HSPA+) (with Google Wallet)': ['4.0.4 '
                                                                        '(IMM76I)',
                                                                        '4.1.2 '
                                                                        '(JZO54K)',
                                                                        '4.2.2 '
                                                                        '(JDQ39)',
                                                                        '4.3 '
                                                                        '(JWR66Y)'],
 '"tungsten" for Nexus Q': ['4.0.4 (IAN67K)'],
 '"volantis" for Nexus 9 (Wi-Fi)': ['5.0 (LRX21Q)',
                                    '5.0 (LRX21R)',
                                    '5.0.1 (LRX22C)',
                                    '5.0.2 (LRX22L)',
                                    '5.1.1 (LMY47X)',
                                    '5.1.1 (LMY48I)',
                                    '5.1.1 (LMY48M)',
                                    '5.1.1 (LMY48T)',
                                    '6.0.0 (MRA58K)',
                                    '6.0.0 (MRA58N)',
                                    '6.0.1 (MMB29K)',
                                    '6.0.1 (MMB29S)'],
 '"volantisg" for Nexus 9 (LTE)': ['5.0.1 (LRX22C)',
                                   '5.0.2 (LRX22L)',
                                   '5.1.1 (LMY47X)',
                                   '5.1.1 (LMY48I)',
                                   '5.1.1 (LMY48M)',
                                   '5.1.1 (LMY48T)',
                                   '5.1.1 (LMY48X)',
                                   '5.1.1 (LMY48Z)',
                                   '5.1.1 (LMY49F)',
                                   '6.0.0 (MRA58K)',
                                   '6.0.0 (MRA58N)',
                                   '6.0.1 (MMB29K)',
                                   '6.0.1 (MMB29S)'],
 '"yakju" for Galaxy Nexus "maguro" (GSM/HSPA+)': ['4.0.4 (IMM76I)',
                                                   '4.1.2 (JZO54K)',
                                                   '4.2.2 (JDQ39)',
                                                   '4.3 (JWR66Y)']}
```

Comment: This is what I went with, though I tweaked it a bit for my code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The following produces a list containing the last entry from each device. To do this you still need to iterate through all of the items, but then just keep the last entry as follows:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup       
import requests


html = requests.get("https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images")
soup = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
models = []

for h2 in soup.find_all('h2', id=True)[1:]:
    tr = h2.find_next('table').find_all('tr', id=True)[-1]
    td = [t.text.strip() for t in tr.find_all('td')]
    models.append([h2.text] + td)

for device, version, link, cs1, cs2 in models:
    print '{}, {}'.format(device, version)
```

This displays the following:

```
"ryu" for Pixel C, 6.0.1 (MXB48K)
"angler" for Nexus 6P, 6.0.1 (MMB29P)
"bullhead" for Nexus 5X, 6.0.1 (MMB29P)
"shamu" for Nexus 6, 6.0.1 (MMB29S)
"fugu" for Nexus Player, 6.0.1 (MMB29T)
"volantisg" for Nexus 9 (LTE), 6.0.1 (MMB29S)
"volantis" for Nexus 9 (Wi-Fi), 6.0.1 (MMB29S)
"hammerhead" for Nexus 5 (GSM/LTE), 6.0.1 (MMB29S)
"razor" for Nexus 7 [2013] (Wi-Fi), 6.0.1 (MMB29O)
"razorg" for Nexus 7 [2013] (Mobile), 6.0.1 (MMB29O)
"mantaray" for Nexus 10, 5.1.1 (LMY49F)
"occam" for Nexus 4, 5.1.1 (LMY48T)
"nakasi" for Nexus 7 (Wi-Fi), 5.1.1 (LMY47V)
"nakasig" for Nexus 7 (Mobile), 5.1.1 (LMY47V)
"tungsten" for Nexus Q, 4.0.4 (IAN67K)
"takju" for Galaxy Nexus "maguro" (GSM/HSPA+) (with Google Wallet), 4.3 (JWR66Y)
"yakju" for Galaxy Nexus "maguro" (GSM/HSPA+), 4.3 (JWR66Y)
"mysid" for Galaxy Nexus "toro" (Verizon CDMA/LTE), 4.2.2 (JDQ39)
"mysidspr" for Galaxy Nexus "toroplus" (Sprint CDMA/LTE), 4.2.1 (GA02)
"soju" for Nexus S (worldwide version, i9020t and i9023), 4.1.2 (JZO54K)
"sojua" for Nexus S (850MHz version, i9020a), 4.1.2 (JZO54K)
"sojuk" for Nexus S (Korea version, m200), 4.1.1 (JRO03E)
"sojus" for Nexus S 4G (d720), 4.1.1 (JRO03R)
```